# Sentry.io integration to GitLab

Tags: gitlab, sentry

I add all needed information about GitLab account in Sentry, but issues from Sentry didn't appear in Gitlab (repository is private and just for test without real code). Please help me to solve problem.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to debug your issue. Please post some logs from sentry/gitlab.

Comment: Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 3):

Sentry doesn't auto-publish issues to issue trackers like GitLab (as it would easily flood most issue trackers). Instead, once you've enabled the integration, your Sentry's issue view will have a "Create issue in GitLab" button.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, the asker is just misunderstanding what the Sentry + GitLab integration is supposed to do.

Comment: Answer is incomplete. While Sentry does not auto-publish issues to issue trackers **by default**, it is possible to enable this behaviour in project settings > "Issue Tracking" > "Automatically create JIRA Tickets".

Comment: Ah, I think this was built this last year, leading up to Atlassian's conference. Thanks for updating!

Answer (score 2):

Note that GitLab 11.8 (Feb. 2019) not offers [Error tracking with Sentry](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/02/22/gitlab-11-8-released/)

> Keeping an eye on errors generated by your application helps maintain a good user experience by detecting problems before users report them and speeding up resolution when they occur.
>
> GitLab 11.8 makes it more convenient and efficient to monitor errors by integrating with popular open source error tracker Sentry, and displaying the most recent errors right within your GitLab project.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_8/error-tracking.png]
>
> Sentry has recently improved their **[GitLab integration](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/01/25/sentry-integration-blog-post/)**, enabling detection of suspicious commits, release and commit tracking, and more. With the combination of both integrations you’ll have a simple path to Sentry from GitLab, as well as a clean way to get to GitLab from Sentry, so that you can always address errors contextually, staying within your existing workflow.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/operations/error_tracking.html) and [issue 55178](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/55178).

---

And, with [GitLab 14.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/10/22/gitlab-14-4-released/#integrated-error-tracking-inside-gitlab-without-a-sentry-instance) (October 2021):

> ### Integrated error tracking inside GitLab without a Sentry instance
>
> Prior to GitLab 14.4, you could integrate with Sentry Error Tracking by supplying an endpoint for a Sentry backend (either self-deployed or in their cloud service). With Gitlab 14.4, you now have access to a Sentry-compatible backend built into your GitLab instance. This allows you to quickly instrument your apps so your errors show up directly in GitLab without the need for a separate Sentry instance.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_4/monitor-integrated-error-tracking.png -- Integrated error tracking inside GitLab without a Sentry instance]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/error_tracking.html#integrated-error-tracking) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/329596).

---

See [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#error-tracking-open-beta) (October 2022):

> ### Error Tracking Open Beta
>
> In GitLab 15.5, we are re-enabling GitLab [integrated error tracking](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/error_tracking.html#integrated-error-tracking) for GitLab.com in [Open Beta](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/product/gitlab-the-product/#open-beta). We’ve reworked the architecture so it uses our new Observability backend, leveraging the ClickHouse database [as a unified data store](/direction/monitor/observability/#unified-data-store). This improvement will enable scaling and a more performant system for the user.
>
> In addition, this sets the groundwork to have errors in the same database as other observability data such as metrics, traces, and logs. We want to allow users to see errors on the same dashboard as other observability data, and enable them to be embedded into issues and incidents.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_5/feature_error_tracking.png -- Error Tracking Open Beta]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/error_tracking.html#integrated-error-tracking) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/opstrace/opstrace/-/issues/1728).

Comment: However links are not highlighted in commit messages :( See issue [#64679](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/64679)